# Plotting different shape 2D arrays in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I couldn't find any answer to this specific case. Say I want to create a scatter plot from the following data:

```
y = np.array([[1,2,3,6,5,3,4,2],[1,2,4,5,5,3,3,2]])
X = np.array([[86],[82]])
```

Where all the values of `y[0]` are the correseponding values of `X[0]` (86) and so on. I know I can just use numpy `repeat` function but I thought maybe there's any other more feasilbe option? I've tried to reshape the any of the arrays but it didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: Transpose the y data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like the tile function from numpy. I dont think there is a way around of "enlarging" X[i] to make it match the length of y[i]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.array([[1,2,3,6,5,3,4,2],[1,2,4,5,5,3,3,2]])
X = np.array([[86],[82]])

for i in range(len(X)):
    plt.plot(np.tile(X[i], len(y[i])), y[i], '.')
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do much. Matplotlib treats each *column* of your data as a separate, broadcastable dataset. So all you need to do is transpose your inputs and let it do its magic.

```
plt.scatter(x.T, y.T)
```

Comment: Thank you. Although i have tried it already. I get an error x and y must be the same size :(